# Probability of casino earning a certain amount

Tags: probability

**Problem**

In a game of dice at a casino, a player throws two dice. There is no initial cost of playing.

If the player gets a 2 or a 12, the player wins $\$200$.

If the player gets a 7, the player wins $\$20$.

If the player gets anything else, the player pays $\$a$ to the casino.

The casino wants to set $a$ such that they, in the long run, make $\$5$ per game. Find the appropriate value for $a$.

**My progress**

Let's call the casino earnings per game $X$.

I've found $P(X=-20) = \frac16$.

Also, $P(X=-200) = \frac1{18}$.

This leaves $P(X=a) = \frac79$.

I assume I'm supposed to use these probabilities as weights, but I can't get a foothold in the calculations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**

$$E[X] = -200 \cdot P(X = -200) + -20 \cdot P(X = -20) + a \cdot P(X=a) = 5$$

Comment: Perfect. I'm still on thin ice when it comes to jumping from probability to statistics, but I see I was on the right track in terms of using the probabilities as weights. Thanks!

Comment: @Aleksander You're welcome! :-)